# How to run animation defind in the Android MotionLayout/MotionScene infinitely?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

I read this document by Google: [Manage motion and widget animation with MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout)
I have also read a few more doc such as [Getting Started with the Motion Editor in Android Studio 4.0](https://riggaroo.dev/getting-started-with-the-motion-editor-in-android-studio-4-0/)

The problem is they both talk about how to start the animation when we click on a View/Button. I want to simulate loading animation but I want to start the anime automatically when I display my view.

I realized that I am able to run the animation using the code below. However, the problem is, `transitionToEnd()` run the animation once.

So, my questions are:

1. how to run the animation and put it in the loop? (to have it forever until I stop it.)
2. Is it possible to run the animation from startToEnd, then endToStart, loop the anime in this way?

```
private fun displayDamLoadingAnimation() {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewgroup_dam_loading, binding.flDamContainer)
        view.motionContainer.transitionToEnd()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably bad for users phone but you can do it.
One way is to create two transitions :

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
    motion:duration="1000">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:autoTransition="animateToStart"
    motion:duration="1000">
```

But if you want it to Loop not go back and forth

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
    motion:duration="1000">
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:autoTransition="jumpToStart"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the transition programmatically and repeat it back and forth using the transition listener. Not sure if that's the most efficient way but I didn't find any other way

```
private void animateText(){
    mMotionLayout.setTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1, float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i) {
            if (motionLayout.getCurrentState() == R.id.start){
                animateText();
            } else {
                mMotionLayout.transitionToStart();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionTrigger(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, boolean b, float v) {

        }
    });
    mMotionLayout.transitionToEnd();
}
```

The "trick" is to check the state once the transition is done and either `transitionToStart()` or re-run the function